# How to send emails in Laravel according to app environment?

Tags: php, laravel, email, events, swiftmailer

I have several controllers that send emails, all of them uses `Illuminate\Mail`, which provides an event called `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` that triggers when a message is being sent.

I would like to intercept the message at that point and change the `$to` variable, replacing whatever value is there with a developer email, depending on the `\App::environment()` value.

I added a listener in the `EventServiceProvider`, receiving an instance of `MessageSending`, which passes `\Swift_Message $event` as parameter to listener's `handle()` method.

However, I'm stuck here. Here's what I did:

```
    // dd()'s are removed in final code, they are here just as examples

    // array with real emails
    dd($event->message->getTo());

    if (!\App::environment('production')) {
        $event->message->SetTo(['developer@test.com']);
    }

    // developer@test.com
    dd($event->message->getTo());

    return $event;
```

It changes $event, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put universal `to` in you `.env` files instead of trying to override it in the event.

So, put this to the `.env`:

```
MAIL_TO_EMAIL=test@test.com
MAIL_TO_NAME=test
```

And then in the `config/mail.php`:

```
'to' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_TO_EMAIL'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_TO_NAME')
],
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#mail-and-local-development

Comment: Thanks, but the dd's are mere examples